# What does the word "waaaaay" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, colloquialisms

In my book, there's a sentence:

> You have **waaaaay** too much time on your hands and you'd like to impress the pretty girl next door with your deep and profound knowledge of MySQL's internals.
>   <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

Although this sentence has a clear meaning without the word "waaaaay", I am curious about this word. What does it mean?

Comment: Someone with deep and profound knowledge of MySQL internals would've found a more efficient way to encode all the `a`. I wouldn't trust that book if I were you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't worry! It's not a new word. It's used as a colloquial emphasis - they're using the extended "aaay"s to emphasise the word way, as someone might use in normal or friendly conversation.

Comment: +1 , yes , it is an emphasis by "stretching" the word in colloquial speech. When represented in text, the word is also "stretched" !

Comment: To add another example, stretching the word "long" in speech might be written "looooong"; "huge" might be "huuuuuge"; "boring" might be "boooorrrrriiiiinnnngggg"... Typically the vowels are repeated, but it's not uncommon (especially for longer words with more consonants) to repeat the consonants as well.  The OP should note that the vowels are always repeated at least three or more times, so that the result could not be misunderstood as a legitimate double-vowel sound (particularly "ee" or "oo").

Answer (score 12):

'way' is an informal intensifer, similar to 'really', 'pretty', or 'very'.

[It has been around for a while](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=way+too+much&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), but much more common (way too common?) in the past twenty years.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/way).

> way 2 2. to a great degree or at quite a distance; far:
>   way too heavy; way down the road.

The grammar is not exactly like that of very' (you can't say "very too much"). You can say "You have a lot of time". You *can* say 'way too ADJ' as in "way too little", or "way too hot"

Comment: +1 , While "way to much" was around for a long time & became more common only in the past 25 years, the usage of "waaay" & "waaaay" started only in the same 25 years. Also, "waay" & "waaaaay" are not used significantly. [[ https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waaay+too+much&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwaaay%20too%20much%3B%2Cc0 ]] & [[ https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waaaay+too+much&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwaaaay%20too%20much%3B%2Cc0 ]]

Comment: @Prem There's nothing spectacular about 'waaa...y' or the number of vowels, specifically with respect to 'way'. It is just an informal eye-dialect manner of showing that the speaker is drawing out the length of the word for emphasis. That is, a search for way, waay, waaay, etc is not particularly salient for what the OP wants to know, especially since English doesn't have repeated 'a's except in rare circumstances.

Comment: Also, the difference between *waay* and *waaaaay* on the one hand and *waaay* and *waaaay* on the other could be entirely negligible.  Google Books NGram Viewer will not return graphs for n-grams with fewer than 40 occurrences, so it's quite possible that of the four spellings @Prem searched for, two were just above 40 and the other two were just below 40.  We can't conclude anything at all about relative frequency from searching Google Books Ngram Viewer in this case.

Comment: Well, I only highlighted that the informal representation of "stretched" "way" started in 1990s (probably by internet users?), and users seem to write 3xA & 4xA much more commonly than 2xA (too short?) or 5xA (much too long?) ; While they all mean the same, "way" is standard and all others are not.

Comment: @Prem See [Supporting Online Material for *Quantitative Analysis of Culture 
Using Millions of Digitized Books*](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/sci/suppl/2010/12/16/science.1199644.DC1/Michel.SOM.revision.2.pdf) section II.3B 'Generation of historical n-grams corpora' and see also section III.0.1 'Sources of bias and error'.

Comment: *"there's nothing spectacular abut waaa..y"* Oh, yes there is something. It may not be spectacular but it's certainly a different way to right the word. It shows that the word is pronounced that way (with over-stretched a"). In some sense, it's a different word as it has a slightly different meaning than "way".